# How to choose color with contourf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, contourf

How can I set the colors for `contourf`?

This is my code:

```
data = fopen ( datafile,'r');   
M = fscanf ( data , '%f', [128, 128]);    
[x,y] = meshgrid(-gr:2*gr/127:gr);  
contourf(x,y,M,[5000 1000 500]);
```

I want to choose color for each of the three area `(5000, 1000, 500)`.

I tried with colormap but doesn't work.

Comment: extract the colormap used with C=colormap. change as you wish. set colormap with colormap(new_C)

Comment: Can you make me an example? I need to use color 1 for area >5000, color 2 for area between 5000 and 1000 and color 3 for area between 1000 and 500 values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a submission on the File Exchange that does exactly what you need. Get it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29638-contourfcmap--filled-contour-plot-with-precise-colormap).

There are 2 versions, depending on whether you use Matlab 2014b or older.

Comment: I tried with this code: clev = [500 1000 5000];
cmap = [0 0.6 0.2; 0 0.8 0.2; 0 1 0.2];
contourfcmap (x,y,Data, clev, cmap); but it give me this: cmap must be nlev-1 x 3 colormap array. why?